# How to use multi-core instead of multi-tread for programming?

Tags: c++, multithreading, raspberry-pi

I'm working on a project (Hardware: RaspberryPI 3B+), which has lots of computation and parallel processing. At present, I'm noticing some sort of lag in the code performance. Therefore, I'm constantly looking for efficient ways to improve my code and its performance.

Currently, I'm using C-language (because I can access and manipulate lower-level drivers easily) and developing my own set of functions, libraries and the drivers, which runs faster than any other pre-defined or readymade libraries or plugins.

Now, instead of the software-based muti-treading (Pthread), I wanted to use the separate cores for performing the corresponding task. So, any suggestion or guideline how I can use the different cores of the RaspberryPI?

Moreover, how can I check the CPU utilization to choose the best core to perform a certain task?

Thanking with regards,
Aatif Shaikh

Comment: "Now, instead of the software-based muti-treading (Pthread), I wanted to use the separate cores" - Where exactly do you think your software threads are executed?  I'll tell you: on the individual cores of the CPU.

Comment: @JesperJuhl somewhat I agree with you, but we can't guarantee whether the software threads are running on single-core or using the multi-core. There might be possibilities is that with the help of any timer, single-core managing different threads. Hence, I need a proper assurance on it.

Comment: You need a multicore-aware scheduler/dispatcher.  Get a kernel that already works and save yourself a humongous mountain of pain:)

Answer (score 6):

At the C/C++ level you do not have access to which CPU core will run which thread. Just use the C++ 11 standard threads and let the OS scheduler to decide which thread runs where.

That said, Linux has the taskset tool to check thread affinity and there 's also [sched_setaffinity](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setaffinity)() function.

Comment: As you mentioned, at the C/C++ level, I don't have the access to set the CPU core for a running specific thread. Can you please tell me which level I can get that access?. switching to a different programming language isn't going to be an issue! Moreover, thanks for this info, the sched_setaffinity() seems to be a pretty useful tool

Comment: At the OS level. I.e. you call functions provided by the OS, not by the C++ standard (you don't change the language, but you link to OS-dependant libraries). I already mentioned sched_setaffinity(), if it is provided by the PI. Windows has another set of related functions.